# Writing to XML files in Excel 2010 corrupts files

Tags: python, xml, excel, corruption

The project I'm working on requires that I programmatically change a .xlsx file to a .zip file, extract all of the files, then make alterations to the underlying XML that makes up an excel spreadsheet. However, I've found that whenever I attempt to write to the file that requires changes, the spreadsheet becomes corrupted once I re-zip the files and changes the extension back to .xlsx. I should note that if I manually change values within the xml files (for example, changing the name of "sheet1" to "test", there are no problems, but I need to do this using python if possible, so that isn't an option.

Does  excel have some sort of checksum/integrity verifier that causes corruption when significant changes are made? If so, what does it look for and is there a way to get around it?

I'm using Windows 7 - 64 bit.

Comment: I'd start by using a diffing tool to compare canonicalized (c14n) versions of both the before and after files.

Comment: BTW, without a reproducer included, this question is arguably too vague to answer.

Comment: Sorry, I've never posted a question on here before. What do you mean by a reproducer?

Comment: Some sample code (that other folks can copy/paste to invoke themselves) that recreates the problem when run. See also http://sscce.org/